# Stored an array in a object and pass it to Code.gs function. Giving reference error

Tags: google-apps-script

What I am trying to do:

1- When someone clicks on the button (class = btn), it retrieves values of the options selected in an array. See the HTML Code.

2- I stored the array into an object - facebookAccountData

3- Pass the data into Code.gs function makeRequest by running google.script.run command.

**When I try to run makeRequest direct from the script editor, I get a ReferenceError. I am not able to do console.log in makeRequest function**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">

<label for="fieldsData">Select Fields:</label>

<select id="fieldsData">
  
<? var data = ACCOUNTDATA.adAccountUIFields ?>
 <? if (data.length > 0) { ?>
<? for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) { ?>
 <option value="<?= data[i] ?>"><?= data[i] ?></option>
   <? } ?>
 <? } ?>

   </select>
</div>    

 <div class="form-group">
 <button id="btn">Run it</button>  
 </div>       
</div>
```

**Javascript HTML**

```
<script>

  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",retrieveFacebookData);
  
  function retrieveFacebookData () {

    var facebookAccountData = {};

    facebookAccountData.facebookFields = $('#fieldsData').val();   // [cpc,impressions,spend]
    google.script.run.makeRequest(facebookAccountData);
    
  }

    
</script>
```

**Code.gs**

```
var ACCOUNTDATA = {
adAccountUIFields : ['cpc','impressions','spend']}


function makeRequest(facebookAccountData) {
   
  facebookAccountData = {facebookFields: [cpc,impressions,spend]};
  console.log(facebookAccountData.facebookFields);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

In line :

```js
facebookAccountData = {facebookFields: [cpc,impressions,spend]};
```

`cpc,impressions and spend` are not defined.

Why you do not do :

```js
const facebookAccountData = {facebookFields: adAccountUIFields};
console.log(facebookAccountData.facebookFields);
```

I advise you using `use strict` mode that help you to not do many errors syntaxs

Comment: And I also advise you to get in the habit of checking that the DOM is ready before doing your actions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I am passing the data because the user will select the field. So if he select two fields that will be added in an array and passed to makeRequestion function. adAccountUIFields is defined in code.gs.

Comment: it works if I do: ```  facebookAccountData = {facebookFields: '[cpc,impressions,spend]'};``` Is this the correct way?